# How to design my database

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a table QUEST which will have  some columns like(id, difficulty, description, etc). Also there are some particular quests that will have specific columns.
In Java I will make particular quest to extend Quest.
But, how is it better to save this in the database? Given the fact that I will be using Hibernate.
My options are:

1. Table Per Hierarchy, where I have a single table, with nullable  columns
2. Table Per Subclass, where I have a table for every class.

Suggestions? Also, in my app, many CRUD operations on those quests are expected

Comment: Table for subclass is my pick of choice